How can I space out images when adding to a post without HTML/CSS/JS?
I use the classic editor and when I have a post with a very large number of images, it's very tedious to hit Enter after each one to space them out.
Is there a way to do this automatically without HTML/CSS/JS? Meaning, no margins, or <p>, no <br>, etc. I just want the <img> tags to be spaced out just as if I had pressed Enter.
Maybe a Chrome extension could work. I am open to that as well.
Is there a way to achieve this? Can I create a plugin to do this? Any help on this would be appreciated.

The only ways I can think of to accomplish this involve CSS and/or Javascript. Since you've requested "without HTML/CSS/JS", your only other option is to press Enter after each one.

I mean no js/css in the post, but I am open to js in an extension to achieve this. Using AI, I have created a plugin that creates a button that asks the user for a count then executes the keystrokes, but it doesn't work well, it just inserts new lines at the top of the post. I don't know how to make it work.
